# Deshabilitar día actual en bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Estoy usando la librería bootstrap-datepicker para un calendario de selección de días, el tema es que necesito deshabilitar/bloquear el día actual para que no se pueda seleccionar... Estoy usando este código CSS:

```
<style>
    .datepicker table tr td.today{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

El problema es que en el datetime aparecen corridos los días y los usuarios se confunden (por ejemplo hoy es martes 25 y aparece martes 26):

[image: Calendario]

El script JS lo tengo así:

```
$('#fecha_mantenimiento').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        language: "es",
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
        todayHighlight: true,
        startDate: '-3d',
        showButtonPanel: true,
    maxDate : 0
    });
```

Alguna forma de hacer que el día actual se muestre pero no sea seleccionable?

Saludos a todos

Comment: [¿Revisaste la documentación?](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo pude solventar así

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);

$('#date').datepicker({ 
    startDate: date
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-group date" id='date'>
   <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Con tu CSS estás desapareciendo u ocultando el div, por eso el día 25 se te desaparece...

PD: La documentación de BS no me funciono como quería. Por eso mejor coloco lo que yo he hecho.

Comment: me funciono, gracias estimado!